# How to get a value of identity column using OUTPUT - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table and a trigger

```
create table test(id int not null identity(1,1) primary key, data int);
create trigger insteadTestInsert ON test INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test(data) select data FROM inserted;
END;
```

When trigger is enabled, the following query

```
declare @tmp_table table(id int, int_val int);
insert into test(data) 
output inserted.* into @tmp_table
values (10);
select * from @tmp_table;
```

returns id = 0, int_val = 10 .
If I disable(or drop) the trigger, the query returns the proper value of `id`.

How to make `OUTPUT` insert proper results into table variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one actually works.

```
declare @tmp_table table(seq int identity, id int, int_val int);
insert into test(data) 
output inserted.data into @tmp_table(int_val)
values (11),(12),(13);

update @tmp_table set id = seq + @@identity - @@rowcount
select * from @tmp_table;
select top 2 * from test order by id desc;
```

The restriction is that you must NOT have any other triggers on the table `test` that would "corrupt" the @@identity variable.

Comment: @a1ex07 - It is not guaranteed that data inserted to the temp table will be in the same order as the data returned from `inserted`.

Comment: @Alex Aza : The only really important field is `id`. I just want to get the records that passed validation in the body of trigger (by joining `@tmp_table` and `test`)

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

> Columns returned from OUTPUT reflect
>   the data as it is after the INSERT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE statement has
>   completed but before triggers are
>   executed.

So the problem is that before your trigger was executed inserted didn't have id set.

Even if remove content of the trigger like this

```
create trigger insteadTestInsert on test instead of insert 
as
begin
    return;
end
```

you will see that `inserted` is still populated although nothing was `inserted` into the table. Basically `inserted` in `output` statement matches `inserted` inside of the trigger.

Comment: Yeah, I read this, but probably not carefully enough. I expected identity column to be populated regardless of whether the record was inserted ; that could be useful to check which rows were actually inserted. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, but it works:

```
declare @tmp_table table(id int, int_val int);
insert into test(data) 
output @@IDENTITY + 1, inserted.data into @tmp_table
values (10);
select * from @tmp_table;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx for details on using @@IDENTITY.

Comment: Hmm... @@IDENTITY - very bad. :). Also would look funny if more than one row inserted, right?

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice alternative, but unfortunately it works only if 1 row inserted.

Comment: You guys are correct.  It will only work if one row is inserted.  I wasn't sure what the use case was, so I posted anyway.